# Create AWS SG and use it

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to create a security group (SG) using Terraform and then use it for an AWS instance.

My config looks like

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my_sq" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  name = "my_sg"
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "my_new_instance" {
  ami = "AMI-ID"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["my_sg"]
  }
}
```

I tried assigning the SG by name and id.
When I ran `terraform plan` everything is all right.
When I tried to apply settings `terraform apply`
I see this error:

```
│ Error: Error launching instance, possible mismatch of Security Group IDs and Names.
```

How do I use the new SG which I created in the config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not create those two things in the right order, since there is no dependency declared between them. Terraform doesn't know that the security group with name "my-sg" is the same as the security group that it is creating with  that name.

You could use a reference to the sg resource in your instance declaration:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  name = "my_sg"
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "my_new_instance" {
  ami = "AMI-ID"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_sg.name]
  }
}
```

or you can [declare a dependency](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on):

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  name = "my_sg"
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "my_new_instance" {
  ami = "AMI-ID"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["my-sg"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.my_sg,]
}
```

If you make the reference to another resource (example 1), then Terraform can itself determine the dependency, and wait for the creation of the security group before creating the instance.